# COM - Controls for PowerBuilder

Tags: powerbuilder

how to use the com controls in PowerBuilder ? If it is used in an application.. how can i identify it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To start with, it'd probably be good to point you towards the manuals, available [online](http://sybooks.sybase.com) and on the product disks, as you don't mention the version of PowerBuilder you're using, and you don't mention the type of COM object you're concerned about, so this answer may be hit and miss. I'm going to assume you're referring to a visual COM control.

Placing it on a window or user object is pretty easy, with the menu item Insert / Control / OLE..., then select the desired OLE control from the dialog. There's also an option in the drop down toolbar item that lists all the controls. Once it's on the window or user object, you can script events on it just like any other control.

To determine if a given control on a window or user object is a COM visual control, if you select it, the title on the Properties pane will say something like "ole_1 inherited from olecustomcontrol". If you're looking at the Edit Source view of the object, search for "from olecustomcontrol". You can similarly do a search across your application for that string to find out where COM controls are used (at least at the first level of inheritance; determining every place will be more complex, looking for descendants of objects that use COM as well).

Good luck,

Terry.